# Setting an environment variable in the shortcut target

Tags: inno-setup

I'm writing a Inno Setup script where I need to create a shortcut that sets an environment variable in the shortcut target. The target string is something like:

```
cmd.exe /c set ENV_VAR=%CD% && "C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe"
```

But for some reason I cannot fantom the shortcut is never created. I checked the length of the target string: 162 characters, which seems to be below the Windows (?) limit. If I create the shortcut with a target string without the "... &&" prefix and then add it by hand, it works as expected, however. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what did you expected as final value of ENV_VAR?

Comment: The directory containing the shortcut.

Comment: Post your [Icons] entry.  Most likely you are not separating the Filename and Parameters properly, but it's hard to tell without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set ENV_VAR using inno setup as **%CD% and "C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe"**
you can use **;**  as like below

**C:\Program Files;C:\Winnt;C:\Winnt\System32**

this might help you

```
set ENV_VAR=%CD%;C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe
```

I have used

```
set ENV_VAR=%PATH%;C:\program files
```

Checked after listing all,there I found

```
ENV_VAR=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Linux For Windows\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\Program Files
```

the above environment variable length is 390 characters , so I believe in your case no issue with length.

Comment: The `&&` in the shortcut "Target" field connects two commands. The environment variable is only to be set to `%CD%`.

Comment: **set ENV_VAR=%CD%** is enough, prior to this you need to set CD value by using   **set CD=xxxxxxxxx** . Use set only.If we use with cmd.exe,environment variables are not creating. **set ENV_VAR=%CD% && "C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe"**   this will set ENV_VAR=the value of CD and then will execute **MyApp.exe**

Comment: Using just `set` doesn't work as this command is only valid within the shell. The `Target` field in a shortcut requires an executable command.